# Write a loop in R to collapse rows based on identical consecutive column values

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, row

I am trying to write a loop in R to collapse rows. Let's say I'm using a data frame like this one:

```
r1 <- c(1, 1,1000,2)
r2 <- c(1, 1001,2000, 2)
r3 <- c(1, 2001,3000, 2)
r4 <- c(1, 3001,4000, 1)
r5 <- c(1, 4001,5000, 3)
r6 <- c(1, 5001,6000, 3)
r7 <- c(2, 1,1000,2 )
r8 <- c(2, 1001,2000, 1)
r9 <- c(2, 2001,3000, 2)
r10 <- c(2, 3001,4000, 1)
r11 <- c(2, 4001,5000, 1)
test <- rbind(r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, r11)
test <- as.data.frame(test)
colnames(test) <- c("chr", "start","end", "abs.sum")
rownames(test) <- NULL
```

This gives me a data frame that looks like this:

```
   chr start  end abs.sum
1    1     1 1000       2
2    1  1001 2000       2
3    1  2001 3000       2
4    1  3001 4000       1
5    1  4001 5000       3
6    1  5001 6000       3
7    2     1 1000       2
8    2  1001 2000       1
9    2  2001 3000       2
10   2  3001 4000       1
11   2  4001 5000       1
```

For each `chr` value, I want to collapse based on identical consecutive `abs.sum`, keeping the lowest value in `start` and the highest value in `end`. So, for example, I would like my final data frame to look like this:

```
  chr start  end abs.sum
1   1     1 3000       2
2   1  3001 4000       1
3   1  4001 6000       3
4   2     1 1000       2
5   2  1001 2000       1
6   2  2001 3000       2
7   2  3001 5000       1
```

I tried writing a for loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(test)) {
        
        if (test$abs.sum[i] == test$abs.sum[i + 1]) {
                test$end[i] <- test$end[i+1]
                test <- test[-i + 1]
                test <- test[-(i + 1),]
        }
        
}
```

Which returns the error:

> Error in if (test$abs.sum[i] == test$abs.sum[i + 1]) { :
> argument is of length zero

I know this isn't correct, but it's what I have been able to piece together so far. I think this may require some combination of "while" and "for" loops, but I am stuck. Maybe a package already exists with a function that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this leveraging run-length id:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(test)[, .(start=min(start), end=max(end), abs.sum=min(abs.sum)), .(chr,rleid(abs.sum))][,-2]
```

Output:

```
     chr start   end abs.sum
   <num> <num> <num>   <num>
1:     1     1  3000       2
2:     1  3001  4000       1
3:     1  4001  6000       3
4:     2     1  1000       2
5:     2  1001  2000       1
6:     2  2001  3000       2
7:     2  3001  5000       1
```

Here is another option using `dplyr` (<strike>but note I retain the use of `data.table:rleid`</strike>. Thanks to @LeroyTyrone for pointing out the `consecutive_id()` function)

```
library(dplyr)

test %>% 
  group_by(chr, id=consecutive_id(abs.sum)) %>% 
  summarize(start=min(start), end=max(end), abs.sum=min(abs.sum)) %>% 
  select(-id)
```

Output:

```
    chr start   end abs.sum
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1     1  3000       2
2     1  3001  4000       1
3     1  4001  6000       3
4     2     1  1000       2
5     2  1001  2000       1
6     2  2001  3000       2
7     2  3001  5000       1
```

Comment: langtang - thank you for the quick reply and a very concise way to do what I requested! In the interest of learning, can you please explain some of the syntax? It looks like you are basically subsetting the object "test", but I have never seen periods before when subsetting. Is this a function specific to the data.table package?

Comment: Yes, you are correct Louise, this is `[i, j, by, ...]` syntax of the package `data.table`.  This package is very widely used for manipulation of data frames. The syntax can be confusing to newcomers to the package. In both cases in my example the `.()` syntax is short for `list()`.  Perhaps you are more familiar with the `dplyr` package for manipulating data frames?  I've added an example using that, but please note that I also use the `data.table::rleid` function within that `dplyr` pipeline, becuase its use here is so key/handy.

Comment: Yes, I typically use dplyr/tidyr. Thank you for explaining the data.table syntax. I will have read more about it for future use.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `dplyr` and `tidyr` method. The workflow is:

1. Create "tmp" column with unique value for each "abs.sum" 'group' using `consecutive_id()`
2. Pivot data to long format by to get all "start" and "end" values into a single column
3. Group data by "chr" and "tmp" and use `filter()` to get the min and max values for each subgroup ("tmp")
4. Pivot data back to wide format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

test %>% 
  mutate(tmp = consecutive_id(abs.sum)) %>%
  pivot_longer(!c(chr, abs.sum, tmp)) %>%
  group_by(chr, tmp) %>%
  filter(value == min(value) | value == max(value)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,
              values_from = value) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-tmp)

# A tibble: 7 × 4
    chr abs.sum start   end
  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1       2     1  3000
2     1       1  3001  4000
3     1       3  4001  6000
4     2       2     1  1000
5     2       1  1001  2000
6     2       2  2001  3000
7     2       1  3001  5000
```

**Update:**
As per @langtang's helpful suggestion, the above can be simplified to:

```
test %>% 
  mutate(tmp = consecutive_id(abs.sum)) %>%
  group_by(chr, tmp) %>%
  summarise(min(start), max(end)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-tmp)
```

Interestingly (for me anyway), on the sample data, the `summarise()` approach is ~3x slower than the pivot approach. Not sure if this scales to larger datasets. Either way, both of these methods are slower than the `data.table` method as outlined in @langtang's answer. Just added it here in case someone is curious about how it could be done solely in the `tidyverse`.

Comment: Updated as `ungroup()` and `select()` were in the wrong order, it is correct now.

Comment: Thank you, Leroy! I really appreciate seeing this done solely in the tidyverse too.

Comment: @LeroyTyrone, I like your use of `consecutive_id` here, but no need to pivot longer and then pivot_wider.. You can simply group by `chr` and `tmp`, and summarize the needed values per those groups.

Comment: @langtang - your advice is most appreciated, I will update my answer accordingly.